# The battery loses its charge itself in an hour

Tags: battery-charging

I have two new li-ion 26650 4800mah unprotected batteries bought 2 days ago. I use a charger for li-ion and li-fe batteries with a balanced cable. 
When I charge these two new batteries it charges them fast up to 4.19-4.2V each. But then when I disconnect the charger the batteries starts to lose their charge up to 3.4v themselves. I have another two batteries with the same characteristics from the same supplier and they work ok. Two old batteries charges like 10 times longer and work great. What can it be?

Comment: You have two bad batteries.

Comment: [Loose](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loose) / [Lose](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lose) Two very different words.

Comment: Are you sure you have Li-Ion batteries, and not LiFePo4? They have "rated voltage" of 3.2V, and you might be trying to overcharge them. Did you try to really load your new batteries, say with a 5-ohm resistor, and see if they really have no charge?

Comment: How reputable is the supplier?

Comment: Yes, it is li-ion. The batteries are exactly the same as I already have. The seller is the biggest network selling electronic components in the country. The batteries have a brand name Rexant on them.

Comment: I’ve loaded them with 11ohms . They charge up 4.2 each and then with load they lose their charge down to 3.6-3.4v in 5-8 minutes and then discharge slowly as if it is their real capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new batteries are dead. It's anyone's guess what happened to them, but the only advice I can give is get them replaced. Sometimes you just get bad stock.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it deserves an answer.
Assuming they are not LiFePo4s or similar, you most likely got fakes (from fab or re-labeled).

To confirm the fake theory you should 1st test for weight. 26650s that are original should have over 90 grams. Anything below it's low quality and/or fake.

You can also now-days get a Li-ion capacity tester which will measure how much capacity you can discharge from them. That will most likely give you a very low capacity compared to the advertised one.

Good fakes will have around 2500mAh (like some red-white ultrafires), other fakes even a few low-end-hundred.

Given the voltage drop, it is more likely that they were previously used (no matter if original or fake) and were re-labeled and resold instead of being recycled.

Comment: Testing for weight won't find those fakes that are mostly filled with sand, and that seems to be a common approach nowadays.

Comment: Yes it will. They don't bother to make it the original weight. I have never seen a fake made so good. Re-labeling is another thing and many re-sellers do it. Many of the vaping sellers re-brand too, but at least they use new cells.

Comment: OK, then I stand corrected. I've never really come across one of the sand-filled ones.